# GPG says that it needs a passphrase but it actually doesn't

Tags: gnupg, signature

I try to use GPG to sign files but something confuses me: If I enter 
    in the terminal (the file I want to sign is called "checksums") it says:

```
$ gpg -s checksums
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "[my name] <[my email prefix]@gmail.com>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID C457C71D, created 2015-01-16
```

However, it doesn't ask me to enter my password but just does the signing process. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GnuPG uses `gpg-agent` to cache your passphrase. It *does* require the passphrase for signing (this is a private key operation) and thus prints the message, but does not need to ask you as the passphrase was still cached. Whether and how long the cache works can be configured.

### gpg-agent

`gpg` checks if there is a running `gpg-agent` (or, in newer versions, necessarily starts one). `gpg-agent` does (among other things) cache your pass phrase for a given time.

### Configuration

This time span can be configured in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, which in my case contains a line

```
default-cache-ttl 600
```

to set the cache time to ten minutes (10*60 seconds). Further options are descriped in `man gpg-agent`, most options can also be used in `gpg-agent.conf` by omitting the leading `--`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this directly answers the question? gpg complaining about a password but still succeeding, and not prompting for a password, is strange behavior that I'm also encountering.

Comment: Indeed -- I added two sentences in front to provide some context.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a gpg agent that caches your password for a period of time, so if you repeatedly use gpg, you only have to enter your password the first time, and then it will be remembered and used automatically on subsequent runs.